# Проверка на совпадение с возможностью выбора следующего действия

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Есть вот такое поле:

```js
$('.add_button').on('click',function(){
  var addVal = $('.add').val();
  if(!addVal=='') {
    $('.result').append('<div class="item">'+
      '<div class="name">'+addVal+'</div>'+
      '<div class="del"></div>'+ // Потом реализую :D
    '</div>');
  } else alert('Вы ничего не ввели');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="add" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter text"/>
<input class="add_button" type="button" value="add"/>
<div class="result"></div>
```

К примеру я ввёл `123123` и дважды нажал на кнопку "add", как сделать так, чтобы на второе нажатие, т.е. на повторное добавление уже существующего значения, было диалоговое окно (Или как правильно) с выбором действия "добавить" или "не добавлять"?

Comment: Может это важно. В дальнейшем поле будет чиститься при добавление => нужно проверять **не** с предыдущим значением, а со списком `result`.

Comment: Создайте массив,перед тем как добавить в массив, делаем поиск по массиву с таким же значением. Если есть выводим диалоговое окно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько вариантов - друг от друга немного отличаются логикой (HTML и CSS одинаковы во всех вариантах):

#### №1

Проверка при добавлении и кратковременная подсветка дубликата в списке:

```js
$('.add_button').on('click', function() {
  var addVal = $('.add').val();
  if (!addVal == '') {
    if (fCheck(addVal)) {
      $('.result').append(`
        <div class="item">
          <div class="name">${addVal}</div>
          <div class="del" onclick="this.parentElement.remove();">×</div>
        </div>
      `);
    }
  } else {
    alert('Вы ничего не ввели');
  }
});

function fCheck(sValue) {
  let bCheck = true;
  $('.result div.name').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == sValue) {
      $(this).on('transitionend', function(ev) {
        $(this).removeClass('blink');
      });
      $(this).addClass('blink');
      bCheck = false;
    }
  });
  return bCheck
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.del {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.blink {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="add" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="add_button" type="button" value="add" />

  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

---

#### №2

Проверка при вводе и блокировка кнопки добавления при наличии дубликата:

```js
$('.add').on('input', function() {
  fCheck($(this).val());
});
$('.add_button').on('click', function() {
  var addVal = $('.add').val();
  if (!addVal == '') {
    $('.result').append(`
      <div class="item">
        <div class="name">${addVal}</div>
        <div class="del" onclick="this.parentElement.remove();fCheck('${addVal}');">×</div>
      </div>
    `);
    $(this).attr('disabled', !fCheck(addVal));
  } else {
    alert('Вы ничего не ввели');
  }
});

function fCheck(sValue) {
  let bCheck = true;
  $('.result div.name').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('blink');
    if ($(this).text() == sValue) {
      $(this).addClass('blink');
      bCheck = false;
    }
  });
  $('.add_button').attr('disabled', !bCheck);
  return bCheck
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.del {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.blink {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="add" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="add_button" type="button" value="add" />

  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

---

#### №3

С диалогом подтверждения и подсветкой последних найденных дубликатов:

```js
$('.add_button').on('click', function() {
  var addVal = $('.add').val();
  if (!addVal == '') {
    if (fCheck(addVal)) {
      $('.result').append(`
        <div class="item">
          <div class="name">${addVal}</div>
          <div class="del" onclick="this.parentElement.remove();">×</div>
        </div>
      `);
    }
  } else {
    alert('Вы ничего не ввели');
  }
});

function fCheck(sValue) {
  let bCheck = true;
  let sCheck = '';
  let result = true;
  $('.result div.name').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('blink');
    if ($(this).text() == sValue) {
      $(this).addClass('blink');
      if (sCheck == '') {
        result = confirm('Один или несколько пунктов с таким значением уже существуют.\n\nДобавить дубликат?');
        sCheck = sValue;
        bCheck = result;
      }
    }
  });
  return bCheck
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.del {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.blink {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="add" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="add_button" type="button" value="add" />

  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, все три варианта отлично работают, спасибо большое)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 принципиально не использую jQuery, но ради ответов приходиться изучать потихоньку))